# How can I use something other than my gem's name for the installation through the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby gem, let's call it "my_very_first_gem." This gem comes with an "install" generator that installs the basic files into a rails application:

`rails g my_very_first_gem:install`

This all works fine, however, given the fact that the name is somewhat long (which is also the case for the real gem name), I don't want to force user's of the gem to type that all out. 'my_very_first_gem:install' is quite a bit longer than say 'devise:install' or 'rspec:install.'

I'm looking for a way to allow user's to either type out the full gem name OR use just the initials to install it:

`rails g mvfg:install`

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried changing the name of your generator class to `MvfgGenerator`?

Comment: My two cents: it doesn't matter, and I think you're over-engineering this . `rails g my_very_first_gem:install` doesn't appear very long, and even if it is, the developer will likely be copy-pasting it from the docs. This is quite honestly the least of your gem writing challenges. Good luck, and thank you for sharing your code with the world!